# Angular project: How can I add modules for each component in a existing tree of components?

Tags: angular, file, module, components

I have angular 10 project. And I have created a component tree such as:

app>main>content>library

Every folder contains the auto-generated files. Eg in the main folder there exist:

```
main.component.css
main.component.html
main.component.ts
```

I would like to add a module for every folder.
When I tried it a module file was generated, thus added to the list above a file:

```
main.module.ts
```

however, after a while, I am getting an error.
Even if I delete the file, the folder stays red.
Have you any idea why this happens?

How could I add a module for each folder-component?

Comment: Please type the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 3):

try this,
`ng g module main` in command prompt
make sure you are in component folders directory before running that command.
as,
`library\content\main> ng g module main`

Now:- what the above command will do is the module.ts will be created inside another main folder as "main>main>main.module.ts
so you just have to copy that module.ts file from there and paste it in the parent main directory.

PS:I am assuming your main.html, main.css, main.ts files are in main folder.